# Sort an array which is sorted in a different way

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I have an array of tuples of type (int, char). It is sorted in lexicographical order:

```
[(0, 'a'), (0, 'b'), (0, 'c'), (1, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (1, 'c') ...]
```

I need to sort it by second element first and then by first element:

```
[(0, 'a'), (1, 'a'), ..., (0, 'b'), (1, 'b'), ..., (0, 'c'), (1, 'c'), ...]
```

What sorting algorithm fit this case the best?

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more one the requirements? (e.g. really fast, not matter what) And the nature of the sets of numbers and chars? (e.g. are they fixed size and continuous?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asymptotically it doesn't make a difference whether you have it sorted in a different manner or not at all. Hence, if you don't care about constant factors, you can use any sorting algorithm you like. The important thing for this task is not so much *which* algorithm you use, but rather how to apply it. So for the sake of the example (in C++, other langs will provide something similar I guess) we will just use `sort()` as provided in `<algorithm>`

To make it very explicit:

```
//the tuple
struct intChar{
    int i;
    char c;
};

//define how our struct evaluates under '<'
bool operator<(const intChar &lhs, const intChar &rhs){
    if(lhs.c == rhs.c){
        return lhs.i < rhs.i;
    }
    return lhs.c < rhs.c;
}
```

Here we say we only want to sort according to the `int`, if the characters are the same. Else sort by `char`.

Then you can just use the regular sorting algorithm: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/ i.e:

```
#include <algorithm>

vector<intChar> toSort;

/*... fill vector ...*/
sort(toSort.begin(), toSort.end());
```

Note: you could actually define other comparisons and pass the comparison-method to be used to the sort method. Here we just overloaded `<`.

Now, if you care about performance and want to squeeze the last bit out then, as suggested in the other solution, you should just use a stable-sort on your second entry. However, the benefit of the above solution is that it will also work for a completely unordered array. If you don't need the general solution and want to drop that overhead and profit from the information you got about your input you can just remove the part:

```
if(lhs.c == rhs.c){
    return lhs.i < rhs.i;
}
```

And then use [`stable_sort()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/stable_sort/) instead of `sort()`. This will save you a constant factor, which as I said in the very beginning does not make any difference for the asymptotic runtime which is O(n*log(n)) in any case.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: Just [stable-sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability) it by your `second element` and you're done.

Longer answer:
Use a `stable` sorting algorithm and first sort by your `first element` and then by your `second element`.

A [stable sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability) guarantees that equal elements remain in the same order.

However if your input is already sorted by your `first element` then you do not have to sort it again. Just stable-sort it by your `second element` and you're done.

Most famous stable sorting alg is most probably `MergeSort`.

Comment: +1 Depending on what Lazin means by "lexicographical order", the tuples may already be in sorted order according to the first element. In that case, only the second sort would be needed and, yes, a stable sort would be required. Of course, I don't know if this buys anything over just defining a new order and resorting with any old algorithm.

Comment: @Patrick87: For the answer as it stands, it does not buy you absolutely anything - you are sorting twice, once for `first` and then for the `second` element. You might save a bit if you only do sort by the second element (since OP said it is already sorted by the first at the beginning). In practice this might help you a bit (iff you are guaranteed that the input is sorted lexicographically). The overhead for having a custom order (and hence a general solution) is a constant factor (of 2), hence, speaking asymptotically, sorting only by the second element does not buy you anything.

Comment: @Patrick87 Of course, when it is already sorted by `first element` this have not to be done another time. I edited my answer. Many "old" algorithms like MergeSort are stable. It's not something "special" or "new" about being a stable sorting alg. :)

Comment: I've thought about something like merge sort without merge phase (because array is already merged). Of cause this will work as needed.

Comment: You got something fundamental wrong in your understanding how sorting works. All sorting in `MergeSort` is done during merge-phase. MergeSort without merge-phase does not make sense at all. And it does not matter which ordered data structure like array or list you are using. This has nothing to do with the alg itself. Beside that I would not recommend to implement it yourself. Just use an existing stable sort in your lib like `stable_sort()`.

Answer (score 0):

A simple method would be:

1. create a collection where you put the tuple-elements colled together, but  "reversed": {1,'a'} => "a1"
   (depending on the case you may need to allow for suitable spaces and/or zeros inserted, for example {1,'a'} => "a01" if the chars are always single but the numbers may have two digits).
2. Sort
3. Unpack again.

The pack/unpack steps are O(n), the sorting is the step that determines performance: O(nLogn)